# python pandas functions with and without parentheses

Tags: python, pandas

I notice that many DataFrame functions if used without parentheses seem to behave like 'properties'  e.g.

```
In [200]: df = DataFrame (np.random.randn (7,2))

In [201]: df.head ()
Out[201]: 
      0         1
   0 -1.325883  0.878198
   1  0.588264 -2.033421
   2 -0.554993 -0.217938
   3 -0.777936  2.217457
   4  0.875371  1.918693

In [202]: df.head 
Out[202]: 
<bound method DataFrame.head of           0         1
   0 -1.325883  0.878198
   1  0.588264 -2.033421
   2 -0.554993 -0.217938
   3 -0.777936  2.217457
   4  0.875371  1.918693
   5  0.940440 -2.279781
   6  1.152370 -2.733546>
```

How is this done and is it good practice ?
This is with pandas 0.15.1 on linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are different and not recommended, one clearly shows that it's a method and happens to output the results whilst the other shows the expected output.

Here's why you should not do this:

```
In [23]:

t = df.head
In [24]:

t.iloc[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-b523e5ce509d> in <module>()
----> 1 t.iloc[0]

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'iloc'

In [25]:

t = df.head()
t.iloc[0]
Out[25]:
0    0.712635
1    0.363903
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

So OK you don't use parentheses to call the method correctly and see an output that appears valid but if you took a reference to this and tried to use it, you are operating on the method rather than the slice of the df which is not what you intended.