# Funny behavior in method of pandas

Tags: python, methods, pandas, dataframe, standard-deviation

I was working with pandas in my IPython window and I accidentally forgot to add the parentheses after a method call to the pandas groupby object:

```
In [68]: df_first.groupby('build_number').std
Out[68]: <bound method DataFrameGroupBy.std of <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f2742f930d0>>
```

But instead of an error or exception that might tell me that I miss out the parentheses, I get the message in `Out[68]`. After putting the parentheses, I then get the expected output:

```
In [69]: df_first.groupby('build_number').std()
Out[69]: 
                     cycles
build_number               
1300          108044.174347
1301          108041.973597
1302          108042.702563
1303          108043.290047
1304          108043.024902
1305          108042.704441

In [70]:
```

So I'm really curious why I did not get an error when I forgot the `()` earlier. Is this a bug in pandas?

Thank you.

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980843/python-pandas-functions-with-and-without-parentheses/27980870#27980870

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with pandas.  When you use parentheses, you call whatever is before the parentheses.  If you don't use parentheses, you just get that object as an object, whatever it may be.  In this case, you have `df_first.groupby('build_number').std`, which is a method object.

You can see the same behavior with all sorts of other functions and methods unrelated to pandas:

```
>>> len
<built-in function len>
>>> list.index
<method 'index' of 'list' objects>
>>> ''.join
<built-in method join of str object at 0x0000000001C93148>
```

Leaving out the parentheses is not necessarily an error.  It allows you to refer to the function/method/callable as an object in itself, to store and perhaps call later.