# what is different between . and () in python

Tags: python, pandas

i'm a beginner of python and i have a question.
(I've been curious about that really really)

when we use pandas in python, we can use function like below

example)

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'name':['Joe','Miachel'], 'age':[20,30]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

to get information, we can use functions

1. df.info()
2. df.info

we can get results from number 1 and 2 both

not only info, but also describe(), describe and
etc...
sometimes i have to use () at the end of code to get a result, but sometimes i don't have to use it

what is different? please teach me about that clearly
thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pandas functions with and without parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980843/python-pandas-functions-with-and-without-parentheses)

Comment: If `info` is just a piece of information (or a property), you use `df.info`.  If `info` is a function, you use `df.info()`.  It's just like any other Python variable.  You have to know this, from the documentation.

Comment: `df.info` doesn't actually give you the info... It says `<bound method DataFrame.info of ...>`, where `...` stands for the `df` repr.

Comment: "we can get results from number 1 and 2 both" no, no you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

`.` names an attribute of an object, while `()` calls it

Some methods can be *represented* and have a similar function to being called a filled `__repr__`, which shows you what they are

In the case of `.info`, it's both callable *and* representable, providing similar information each time

Simply refer to the docs or explore for an instance of any particular object!

You can use `dir()` to list the methods on an object or `help()` to get generated info (potentially quite detailed)

```py
>>> o = object()
>>> o
<object object at 0x10d73efb0>
>>> o()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'object' object is not callable
```

Here's an example with 3 very simple classes (classes inherit from object if they don't specify some base class)

```py
class Foo():
    pass

class Bar():
    def __repr__(self):
        return "called __repr__ on an instance of Bar"

class Baz():
    def __call__(self):
        return "called an instance of Baz"
```

Now we can see how they behave when represented or called!

```py
>>> a = Foo()
>>> b = Bar()
>>> c = Baz()
>>> a
<__main__.Foo object at 0x113d1ff40>
>>> b
called __repr__ on an instance of Bar
>>> c
<__main__.Baz object at 0x1041f7a30>
>>> a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Foo' object is not callable
>>> b()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Bar' object is not callable
>>> c()
'called an instance of Baz'
```

```py
>>> dir(c)
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

`help(c)`

```py
Help on Baz in module __main__ object:

class Baz(builtins.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
 |  __call__(self)
 |      Call self as a function.
 |
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```

Comment: As I have trouble with it and the line is fuzzier in Python, more on methods vs attributes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312470/difference-between-methods-and-attributes-in-python

Comment: *"In the case of `.info`, it's both callable and representable, providing similar information each time"* -- That's not correct; OP is mistaken.

Comment: Many methods of Pandas DataFrames are representable with information about the DataFrame (in this case, its contents in two different views) .. displaying it does _not_ call it, however, which should be clear, or more specifically, the representation of `.info` is _not_ the same as it being called! (though it could be, this would also be somewhat confusing)

Comment: I really appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: @이영훈 anytime! If this or other Answers solve your Questions, please mark them as the Answer with the check to its left to help yourself and the community!